# .htaccess file rewrite rule check

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, open-source

I want to rewrite my apache mod_rewrite pattern. I use to do with following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /^([^A-Z0-9a-z]+)\.html /search.php?search_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

With the above rule I can't get what I expecting.
Can anyone tell what is wrong with my code and how to solve it.

Edited.
my requirement is simple.
I want to redirect if i enter /1.html to /search.php?search_id=1

Thats it.

Comment: What is it you are expecting?

Comment: @faa i have edited my question..please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !search\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([0-9]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule  .*    search.php?search_id=%1    [L,QSA]
```

Maps silently

`http://example.com/FileID.html`

To:

`http://example.com/search.php?search_id=FileID`

`search.php` is considered a fixed string, while `FileID` can be any number.

For permanent redirection, replace `[L,QSA]` with `[R=301,L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your rule try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([^A-Z0-9a-z]+)\.html /search.php?search_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

By the way you could also try to use this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^A-Z0-9a-z]+)\.html /search.php?search_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

This makes the leading slash optional.

Answer (score 0):

Are you typing 1.html after the domain? That is if your domain is example.com, then you type example.com/1.html?
If it is you are doing then don't use / before the regular expression in .htaccess file.

Try adding the following into your main .htaccess file. That is located in the directory which has your home page of the website:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html/?$ /search.php?search_id=$1 [NC, L]
```

I have used RewriteBase as a comment. If you use a shared server then keep it as a comment or delete the line.

EDIT: [NC, L] use to tell that, NC flag for rule no need to be case sensitive (no case) and L flag for stop if this was matched.